# How For Loop is generating dynamic table?

Tags: php

My teacher has shown us the following script:

```
<table border="1" width="600" height="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<?php
$iNew=1;
echo '<tr>';
for ($iCounter=1;$iCounter<=15;$iCounter++)
{
    echo '<td>'.$iCounter.'</td>';
    if ($iNew==3) {
        echo '<tr></tr>';
        $iNew=0;
    }
    $iNew++;
}

echo '</tr>';
?>
</table>
```

Here, the `<tr>` tag is inside the `<td>` tag. In normal HTML this does not work because cell tags must be inside row tags, but when run in the above php, the appropriate number of columns appear. How is this script actually working?

Comment: Your question is written horribly :/ I'm so confused.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? What do you think is happening?

Comment: That script will generate bad HTML. You will want `echo '</tr><tr>';`

Comment: why don't you look at the source of the page generated by this code? You can always add extra echoes,  e.g. `echo 'here I am'` to see WHERE each particular bit of the page comes from in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
if ($iNew==3)
{
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $iNew=0;
}
$iNew++;
```

You had TRs reversed, creating a new row and ending it immediately instead of ending the previously created row and then starting a new one!

Comment: min code above is working perfectly! The only thing I am not able to understand is how tr is generating new column when it is placed inside the td tag! There is nothing wrong and reversing the tags isn't required.

Comment: It's not placed within the TD tags, the TD tags are closed everytime, but right after, you have a counter that is incrementing, and each 3 TD, it will output a new line, thats all!

Comment: ok that cleared it a bit and sorry fox for putting the question in a horrible way...just learning php ..thanks everyone!

Comment: and also you were right about the code...i had the trs reversed my bad :(